# Recargar una vista parcial desde JQuery o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

esta vez me encuentro con una duda que buscando en varios foros no he logrado resolver, tengo un listado de notificaciones, que las cargo en una vista parcial, luego invoco esta vista en un layout. hasta ahi todo bien.

Luego tengo un `script` que al hacer clic en alguna notificacion me cambia su status a visto, si recargo la pagina ya no me aparece, pero lo que quiero es que al hacer clic solo me recargue la vista parcial o me remueva el elemento de mi lista. Solo encontre el evento `reload()` pero no sirve para lo que busco, intente llamando de nuevo la vista si el ajax se completa pero tampoco funciono.

Parte del layout donde invoco a la vista parcial

```
    <ul id="alerta1" class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
        @Html.Action("Not", "EntrevistaIdioma")
       <li><a href="" style="text-align:center;">Ver mas...</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Mi vista parcial

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {

    <li id="btnAlerta" class="alerta btn btn-default">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombreCand) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellidoCnad)
    </li>
    <input id="candidato" value=@item.EntrevistaIdiomaID type="hidden">
 }
```

Mi script

```
<script>

$(function () {
    $("#btnAlerta").click(function () {

        var url="@Url.Action("Visto","EntrevistaIdioma")";
        var id= $("#candidato").val();
        var data = { id: id };
        location.reload();
        $.post(url, data).done(function (data) {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: no es necesario recargar la vista parcial, en la funcion done del post deberias ocultar la notificacion que hiciste clic.

Comment: tienen algo que ver c# y asp.net en esta pregunta?

Comment: bueno, la aplicacion la estoy haciendo en asp.net con c# por eso puse dichas etiquetas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

<li id="btnAlerta" class="alerta btn btn-default @item.EntrevistaIdiomaID">
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombreCand) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellidoCnad)
</li>
<input id="candidato" value=@item.EntrevistaIdiomaID type="hidden"> }
```

arriba colocamos el id en la class de la etiqueta li y ahora...`

```
 $(function () {
$("#btnAlerta").click(function () {

    var url="@Url.Action("Visto","EntrevistaIdioma")";
    var id= $("#candidato").val();
    var data = { id: id };
    $.post(url, data).done(function (data) {$(".@item.EntrevistaIdiomaID").css(display:'none');
    });});});
```

con lo cual como te a dicho el compañero pues ocultas la notificacion especificada con la propiedad css display none despues del done de los datos y la peticion